# How do I center a form which is wrapped in a flex container?

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">My Awesome App</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is why you should download this fantastic app!</p>
  <p>Want to know more?</p>
  <p>Join our mailing list!</p>
  <hr>
  <form class="form-inline" id="jumbo-form">
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Sign Up Now</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

In the class of jumbotron, all content before the form is centered. However, the form is align left. I tried the solutions from other questions like adding absolute position and then margin:auto but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your form is a flex container and flex can be horizontally center with
>   `justify-content: center;` and vertically with `align-items: center` (If height is enough available)

Add below css and this will center the form

```
.form-inline {
 justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap and the i would suggest using it strictly. Surround your form within `Container`, `row`, `col`. If you want to give padding or margin, use bootstrap classes. 
In this case:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        Your Form goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Have a look here: `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/`

Comment: Thanks! It is a good suggestion. I should make better use of the grid system.

Answer (score 0):

in your `"form-inline"` display is set to `"flex"` so you can add `"justify-content:center;"` to its css code or you can add `"justify-content-center"` to "class" attribute in your html.

Comment: your welcom. if you find it useful you should choose an answer and clarify that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

add this class inside the container class

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    Your Form
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="row text-center">
     Your Form
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the parent element prevent the element to get aligned as desired. It limits not only `center` but `float` as well.I tried to explain this in the following image.
Please inspect the width of the parent element.Hope you will find this helpful.
[image: Common issue while aligning content to the center]

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are using **Bootstrap** so try this :

```
<div class="container"> <div class="row justify-content-center"> Your Form  </div> </div>
```

Have a look here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/

Or use css as following: 
.

```
form-inline{
       justify-content:center
}
```